# Getting Data From A Specific Website Using Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a machine learning project and I have to get data from a website every 15 minutes. And I cannot use my own computer so I will use Google cloud. I am trying to use Google Compute Engine and I have a script for getting data (here is the link: https://github.com/BurkayKirnik/Automatic-Crypto-Currency-Data-Getter/blob/master/code.py). This script gets data every 15 mins and writes it down to csv files. I can run this code by opening an SSH terminal and executing it from there but it stops working when I close the terminal. I tried to run it by executing it in startup script but it doesn't work this way too. How can I run this and save the csv files? BTW I have to install an API to run the code and I am doing it in startup script. There is no problem in this part.

Comment: The answer differs if you are using Compute Engine or App Engine. You have both tagged, which are you actually using?

Comment: @BrettJ I want to use compute engine but I can also use app engine if it's required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instances running in Google Cloud Platform can be configured with the same tools available in the operating system that they are running. If your instance is a Linux instance, the best method would be to use a cronjob to execute your script repeatedly at your chosen interval.

Once you have accessed the instance via SSH, you can open the crontab configuration file by running the following command:

```
$ crontab -e
```

The above command will provide access to your personal crontab configuration (for the user you are logged in as). If you want to run the script as root you can use this instead:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

You can now edit the crontab configuration and add an entry that tells cron to execute your script at your required interval (in your case every 15 minutes).

Therefore, your crontab entry should look something like this:

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/you/script.sh
```

Notice the first entry is for minutes, so by using the */15, you are telling the cron daemon to execute the script once every 15 minutes.

Once you have edited the crontab configuration file, it is a good idea to restart the cron daemon to ensure the change you made will take place. To do this you can run:

```
$ sudo service cron restart
```

If you would like to check the status to ensure the cron service is running you can run:

```
$ sudo service cron status
```

You script will now execute every 15 minutes.

In terms of storing the CSV files, you could either program your script to store them on the instance, or an alternative would be to use Google Cloud Storage bucket. File can be copied to buckets easily by making use of the gsutil (part of Cloud SDK) command as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp). It's also possible to mount buckets as a file system as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets).